# How do I go about building a native iOS rich text editor?

Tags: ios, native, text-editor, richtext

We want a native rich text editor because we are trying to stay away from using Javascript and webviews for this solution.

We've tried many things so far, and we're left with quite a few obstacles that we just can't get around.  Let me break it down into questions that I hope you can answer.

1. I have a UIButton, that says "B" on it, and I want to put it into the 'selected' state when a user sets 'Bold' from using the TextView's long-press gesture on a selection.  How do I register for this state change?  I tried adding an observer on the textView.attributedText, but it doesn't seem they are changing that dictionary, but instead are updating it.  NSDictionary has no way, as far as I know, to add observers on the dictionary's keys.  So I'm stuck with noticing this change.
2. Regarding number 1, I also tried setting the textView's inputDelegate and it seems that the method - (void)textDidChange:(id )textInput never gets called. :(  Docs says is should. What did I do wrong?
3. How do I update the attributedText weight when I hit my bold italic or underline button.
4. How do I convert my attributed text into HTML?

I saw a few neat libraries for number 4, but I'm still curious what you'd come up with. (Broadens my options).  But, I can't really work on number 4 until I figure out how to do the previous 3.

This editor will also need hyperlinks, bulleted lists, and numbered lists, more things I imagine I'll struggle through, but if you could answer the 4 questions above, that will keep me held over for a while. :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Here is a link to an iOS rich text editor I've been working on.
https://github.com/aryaxt/iOS-Rich-Text-Editor

There is still a lot of work that has to be done, but the basic features are there.

Answer (score 2):

The Apple sample application called 'TextEdit' does much of what you've described and, if not that, would be a very good starting point.  Find the sample code with a search in the Organizer.

Answer (score 0):

There is a commercial editor based on the DTCoreText library. I've used that library but not the rich text editor. Look at the Cocoanetics web site. It's not cheap but will save you a ton of work.